# How do I apply custom Validation on an array?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

My problem is fairly complex and kind of difficult to explain with text, so I will try my best.

I have three inputs, all as arrays, 'A' 'B' 'C'. I also have a checkbox input 'D' (not an array). Every element in A has to be required if the corresponding element in B or C is non-empty, BUT, if D has a value of 1, A shouldn't be required even if the corresponding elements in B or C are non-empty. If A[1] is empty, and B[1] is empty but C[1] is non-empty, I would like only A[1] to be required, not A[0] or A[2].

I created some rules to try and solve this, but i'm unsure how to solve it.

```
$validator = Validator::make($output, [
]);

$validator->sometimes('A.*', 'required', function($input){
    if ($input->D==1){//if checkbox D is checked, don't make A required regardless of anything else
        return false;
    }
    if (($input->B!=null) || ($input->C!=null)){//Problem: instead of doing it for the individual elements 
    //it will make A required if any element of B or C is non-empty
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Definetely you need to write a custom.validation rule. With inbuilt validation rule you cannot meet such a complex requirement. If you requirement is just require A elements if elements in B,C present and when Check box D not 1 , you may use `requireWithAll` rule.

```
if(!$request->has('D') || $request->input('D') != 1){
        $rules = [
            'A.*' => 'required_with_all:B.*,C.*'
        ];

        $messages = [
            'A.*.*.required_with_all' => 'All A Elements are required if corresponding B and C elements present',

        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$messages);
        if($validator->fails()){
            $this->throwValidationException($request,$validator);
        }
    }
```

simply paste the above code where you want to do the validation, this is simple way to meet your requirement rather writing complex custom rules, however please note that all of the array indexes must be similar among A,B,C..

Comment: I'm sorry I am absolutely terrible with validation. For Custom Validation could you please maybe provide a template on how I would go about doing something like this?

Comment: Are all corresonding array elements indexes are same?

Comment: And what about if A1 and B1 is not empty but C1 is empty, do you want the validation rule to require C1

Comment: I have updated my answer above, try to execute it and let me know your feed back, if its works donot forget to thumbs up my answer .